# How do I use Nodejs & Redis using WebSockets?

Tags: node.js, redis

Have checked a few guides & the Original docs but I can't find a clear description of how it works. Even ChatGPT gave multiple suggestions that didn't work.

I have a NodeJS server running Express & am integrating it with Redis for WebSockets. I'm using WebSockets, not SocketIO (however, if you provide a solution with SocketIO that's okay too). I'm also using the free version of the server provided by Redis.

I keep getting this error.

```
Socket error [ErrorReply: ERR Can't execute 'publish': only (P)SUBSCRIBE / (P)UNSUBSCRIBE / PING / QUIT / RESET are allowed in this context]
```

Here's a simplified version of my app.js

```
const PackageJson = require("./package.json");
const redis = require('redis');

module.exports = (async () => {
  const {Config} = await require("./common/config");

  // ==============================================
  // Base setup (Not really important for this part, but left here for question)
  // ==============================================

  process.env.TZ = "Etc/GMT";
  const express = require("express");
  const session = require("express-session");
  const app = express();
  const server = require('http').createServer(app);
  const WSServer = require("ws").Server;
  wss = new WSServer({server: server,});
  const port = process.env.port || 3000;
  const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
  app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '1500mb'}));
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '1500mb', extended: true, parameterLimit:1500000}));
  app.use(require("express-useragent").express());
  app.use(session({secret: "keyboard cat",resave: false,saveUninitialized: true,cookie: { secure: true },}));
  app.use(async (req,res,next) => {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    req.session.language = req.query.lg;
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, auth-uid, auth-token,");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","PATCH, POST, GET, DELETE, OPTIONS");
    next();
  });

  // ===============================================================
  // Routes
  // ===============================================================

  app.get("/", (req,res) => {res.send(
    "<html><head></head><body>API is running <br>"+
      "App: "+Config.FrontEnd.AppName+"<br>"+
      "Env: "+Config.Env+"<br>"+
      "Version: "+PackageJson.version+"<br>"+
    "</body></html>"
  );});

  // ==============================================
  // Redis
  // ==============================================

  const redisClient = redis.createClient({
    password: Config.Keys.RedisPassword,
    socket: {
        host: Config.Keys.RedisUrl,
        port: Config.Keys.RedisPort
    }
  });

  redisClient.on('error', err => console.log('Redis Sub Client Error', err));

  // Seems to be connecting fine, if I insert a wrong password an error is thrown
  await redisClient.connect();
  // Am unable to confirm if it's actually subscribing or not
  await redisClient.subscribe('my-channel');

  // ==============================================
  // Sockets
  // ==============================================

  wssRooms = {};
  wss.on("connection", function connection(ws) {
    ws.on("message", async function incoming(message) {
      redisClient.publish("my-channel",message)
    });
  });

  // Doesn't console log
  redisClient.on('subscribe', (channel, count) => {
    console.log(`Subscribed to Redis channel ${channel} count ${count}`);
  });

  // Doesn't console log either
  redisPubClient.on('message', (channel, message) => {
    console.log(`Received message from Redis channel ${channel}: ${message}`);
  });

  // ==============================================
  // Start the server
  // ==============================================
  server.listen(process.env.PORT || port, () => {
    console.log(Config.FrontEnd.AppName+` Listening on port:${process.env.PORT || port} Env:${Config.Env}`);
  });
})();
```

Also, I need to use redis or some sort of function because we have multiple API servers behind a load balancer, so currently some clients do not get updates when they should.